# Utilizing File Api for File Access in Android 11

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm experiencing some interesting behavior on a few Android 11 devices in regards to reading and writing to external storage. I know some changes were implemented with Android 10/11 in regards to storage but I was under the assumption than an app could access it's own app-specific directories (internal and external) without incident. Any suggestions are welcome.

Device #1: Throws the EPERM Error (Operation Not permitted) when writing to the removable external storage card with the following code:

```
  val externalDirectories = applicationContext.getExternalFilesDirs(null)

    externalFile =
                File(externalDirectories[1].path + "/sampletextfile.txt")

            externalFile.writeText("sample text")
```

Here's the stack trace:

> java.io.IOException: close failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)                                                                                                    at libcore.io.IoBridge.closeAndSignalBlockedThreads(IoBridge.java:254)                                                                                                      at java.io.FileOutputStream.close(FileOutputStream.java:431)                                                                                                        at java.io.FileOutputStream.finalize(FileOutputStream.java:500)                                                                                                     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:291)                                                                                                       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:278)                                                                                                      at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)                                                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)                                                                                                  Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: close failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)                                                                                                   at libcore.io.Linux.close(Native Method)                                                                                                    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.close(ForwardingOs.java:88)                                                                                                  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:110)                                                                                                     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.close(ForwardingOs.java:88)                                                                                                  at libcore.io.IoBridge.closeAndSignalBlockedThreads(IoBridge.java:252)                                                                                                      at java.io.FileOutputStream.close(FileOutputStream.java:431)                                                                                                        at java.io.FileOutputStream.finalize(FileOutputStream.java:500)                                                                                                     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:291)                                                                                                       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:278)                                                                                                      at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)                                                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

Device #2: It is able to perform the above code successfully but cannot provide a list of files from a directory. The code below always yields false:

```
externalDirectories[1].canRead()
```

Also, and to add, the following always returns null even when there are files in the directory:

```
externalDirectories[1].listFiles()
```

Comment: I would not rely on `canRead()`. Regarding device #1, you might consider posting a complete stack trace.

Comment: Thanks, I added the stack trace above, and a few additional comments.